# Electron+nuxt+amCharts 4: Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, electron, nuxt.js, amcharts

I want to code a desktop application using Electron, nuxt.js and am4charts. When importing the am4charts core with

`import * as am4core from '@amcharts/amcharts4/core'`

the app returns an error:

```
export { System, system } from "./.internal/core/System";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

My setup:

- Electron-nuxt boilerplate (https://github.com/michalzaq12/electron-nuxt)
- "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.7.1"

I already tried to transpile amCharts in nuxt.config.js using

```
  build: {
    transpile: [
      '@amcharts/amcharts4'
    ],
    vendor: ['v-tooltip']
  }
```

but without success. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you use JavaScript or do you use Typescript for development? The `export { ... }` syntax which causes your error is Typescript syntax, not JavaScript. You cannot import a Typescript module into a JavaScript file.

Comment: It could be related to a number of things but you might try checking the "issues" section of the Github project you're piggybacking off of to see if others have the same issue. For context, `export` is not exclusive to Typescript rather it is part of the ES2015 spec that is commonly (thanks to webpack) transcompiled by Babel (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/learn/) into CommonJS.

Comment: Did you configure typescript or babel in the boilerplate?

Comment: @oktapodia configured babel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it could be known issue between nuxt.js and amcharts.js and it has a solution as follows:

> create a file plugins/amcharts.js

```
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";
import am4themes_dark from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/dark";

import Vue from "vue";

Vue.prototype.$am4core = () => {
  return {
    am4core,
    am4charts,
    am4themes_animated,
    am4themes_dark
  }
}
```

> then add to nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
    {
      src: '~/plugins/amCharts.js',
      ssr: false
    }
  ],
```

> in components file

```
mounted() {
     let {am4core, am4charts, am4themes_animated, am4themes_dark} = this.$am4core();
 }
```

Solution is found on Github: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3336

Answer (score 0):

in the nuxt.config.js file enter the code below

```
build: {
        transpile: ['@amcharts/amcharts4']
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.